# SQLite issue with insert not unique

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a button in my project that inserts a record into my SQLite database.
but there is an issue cus I have unique index so if the insert is a dup it will error out and quit the function.. how can I prevent from showing an error and quitting?

SQLite error (2067): abort at 11 in [INSERT INTO my_success VALUES('123456')]: column myids is not unique
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll

Comment: Post a small reproducible sample. Show us the code you are using that causes the issue. Also, since this is about your databases, explain/show the schema of that table. For instance, let us know what columns you have, what types they are and what is your primary key.

Comment: could you provide the table structure & the related `Model` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best solution, but you should be able to catch the exception:

```
try
{
    // put your SQLite insert code here...
}
catch(System.Exception)
{
}
```

Comment: yeah, I tried that and it works but Is there a way to do it without the try/catch ?

Comment: @XK8ER - Why do you not want to use a Try Catch?  That's what they're for!

Comment: I am just wondering because when I am running the app from visual studio it takes longer since it needs to print out thousands of debug text in the immediate window..